# What are these funnel-looking green things in my yard?

Tags: irrigation

There are 5 or 6 of these funnels on stakes in my back yard from the previous owner. Are they insect bait/poison stations? Repellent stations for chipmunks? (not working in that case!)

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

These are Hose Guides.  They're usually placed near deck posts and similar obstructions to stop your water hose from kinking when you pull it around a corner.  They're also used near gardens to stop you dragging the hose through the garden and ruining your planting. Possibly [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FJTWI2):

[image]

Comment: oooo. do they spin, or are they supposed to work just by their shape? I might need some.

Comment: Some spin. Some slide. These look like a two-piece design, which implies that they spin.

Comment: Doooh! They ARE set up near a water spigot and around a garden bed (though not much is growing in it these days)

Comment: I think that Amazon link is the exact product in the question.  You can see residual from the sticker that 90% of the reviews are complaining about.

Comment: Handy for guiding plug-in lawn mower cords too.

Comment: Can confirm that they spin and they do an OK job at guiding a hose :)